# Using python, how to get names of running services on linux

Tags: python-3.x, linux, service

i have a small service neo.service file on linux

```
[Unit]
Description= dev script
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
[Service]
Environment="POSTGRES_PASS="
Environment="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/PostgreSQL-11/postgresql-11.0/lib/"
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=fmciodmsapp
ExecStart=python3 session_initiator.py config_as_initiator POSTGRES_CONFIG

 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Service is launched on linux using:

```
sudo systemctl start neo
```

Using python, how do I write a code to display running processes. I wrote this below based on an advice on other forum.

```
def get_list_of_processes():
    listOfProcObjects = []
    import psutil
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
       try:
           pinfo = proc.as_dict(attrs=['pid', 'name', 'username'])
           pinfo['vms'] = proc.memory_info().vms / (1024 * 1024)
           listOfProcObjects.append(pinfo);
       except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
           pass
    listOfProcObjects = sorted(listOfProcObjects, key=lambda procObj: procObj['vms'], reverse=True)

    return listOfProcObjects
```

To list the processes, I do this (because the processes launched are by user ID serviceuser

```
for a in x:
    if a['username'] == 'serviceuser':
        print(a)
```

Output is:

```
{'name': 'python3', 'username': 'serviceuser', 'pid': 24500, 'vms': 749.0859375}
{'name': 'python3', 'username': 'serviceuser', 'pid': 24406, 'vms': 612.59375}
{'name': 'httpd', 'username': 'serviceuser', 'pid': 31539, 'vms': 419.37890625}
{'name': 'httpd', 'username': 'serviceuser', 'pid': 31540, 'vms': 355.37890625}
```

Obviously, judging by the output, you can see that there are two python processes running. My challenge is - how do I know which one is

```
python3 session_initiator.py config_as_initiator POSTGRES_CONFIG
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the process command line to `attrs` (attributes).

Have a look at `as_dict` in this page:

https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.as_dict

I think the `cmdline` attribute is what you need.